# Get link from html by php

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

How do I get this link `<li><a rel="prev" href="/1149/" accesskey="p">&lt; Prev</a></li>` from an html document using PHP? How do I get the link by the "rel"?
I'm trying to get `/1149/`

Comment: you have to use regex and jquery

Comment: You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. They are not up to the task. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to understand what you want… If you want to take an HTML/XML input and grab the href value of a link with the attribute rel="prev" I'd suggest using DOMXpath, something like:

```
$html = '<li><a rel="prev" href="/1149/" accesskey="p">&lt; Prev</a></li>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//a[@rel='prev']") as $node) {
    if ($node->hasAttribute('href')) {
        echo $node->getAttribute('href') . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get `/1149/`